Airflow | Is Roll your own api authentication feature not available in airflow version greater than > 2.8.0?
Is Roll your own api authentication feature not available in airflow version greater than 2.8.0.
In latest airflow release documentation this part is missing.
In latest airflow release documentation this part is missing and there is no infomration in release notes.
